# how to compare DateTime Column with Only Date not time

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am using mySql and my table column `date` is DATETIME type

But i want to compare only today's date not time

```
       $today = date("Y-m-d",  time());
```

IF i compare date using above method it always come wrong.

```
$this->update("
UPDATE `stats_tracker` 
SET 
  `user_agent`='$this->visitor_user_agent' , 
  `referrer`='$this->referrer_page' , 
  `page_views`='$page_views' 
WHERE 
  `visitor_ip`='$this->visitor_ip' 
  AND `page`='$this->this_page' 
  AND `date`='$today'");
```

Please Help me i am not a good mySQL programmer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

there is a mysql function called DATE which extract the date part of a date or datetime expression

```
AND DATE(`date`)='$today'
```

edit: be carefull, as said in the comments below, using this will bypass index on datetime field. You should use instead :

```
AND date BETWEEN '$today 00:00:00' AND '$today 23:59:59'
```

Comment: You should not use this since it would kill the index on date column slowing down the query

Comment: I'm not sure to undertand, what would you suggest to not "kill the index" ?

Comment: you need to compare date column using between function assuming you want rows for jan 1st 2013 you need to do :    where date between '2013-01-01 00:00:00' and '2013-01-01 23:59:59'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [datediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function like this:

```
AND datediff(`date`, '$today') = 0
```

Comment: unfortunately this also doesn't use index on the `date` column (at least not on mysql 5.1)

Answer (score 0):

```
date_format('%Y-%m', time())
```

is probably the function you need to use to do the compare.

Comment: that won't help, because incomplete datetime entry is automatically completed by mysql assuming time part = 0, so it would match only on midnight, not on other times during the day

Comment: You use the wrong direction for the parameters: according documentation [DATE_FORMAT (date, format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)